# Google Analytics 4 tag confusion

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

A new version of Google Analytics was released [Google Analytics GA4](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en) in the last few weeks we have had three new tags appear.

I would like to suggest a synonym clean up of them now rather than wait. There haven't been enough questions asked yet for that to happen directly.  I was hoping an admin would do a clean up for me.

The first one is the tag i created and the one i would personally suggest that we stick with as the main tag.

- [google-analytics-ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-ga4)
- [google-analytics-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-4)
- [ga4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ga4)

Comment: While we're here, both the google-analytics-ga4 (source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4) and google-analytics-4 (source: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2020/06/02/implement-google-analytics-4-properties-website-mobile-app/) tag wikis have been plagiarised

Comment: I think [tag:google-analytics-4] makes more sense than the more verbose [tag:google-analytics-ga4]. We can make [tag:ga4] a synonym to avoid the tag creeping up and improve the experience for those who prefer the GA4 abbreviation. Overall, thumbs up - the sooner we deal with it, the better.

Comment: The first tag looks to be redundant as it looks that the `ga4` stands for *Google Analytics 4*. By the other hand Google docs use "Google Analytics 4 property" i.e. [Upgrade to a Google Analytics 4 property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9744165?hl=en). By the other hand Google doesn't use versioning for the web apps / services, before this I have only saw the use of versionin in APIs like Sheets API 4.

Comment: OK, on [How to tag for both Universal Analytics and Google Analytics 4 properties](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/basic-tag?technology=gtagjs) use Google Analytics 4 property and GA4

Comment: @Rubén - then we can make the tag be named the official way [tag:google-analytics-4-property], make a synonym of [tag:google-analytics-4] (or vice versa) + synonymize [tag:ga4] to all this - should take care of things :) For other readers: [tag:google-analytics-v4] is a synonym of [tag:google-analytics-firebase] and should not be confused with Google Analytics 4 property (...).

Comment: @OlegValter  the issue with google-analytics-4 is that it may be confused with the Google-analytics-reporting-api which is technically Google analytics api v4,  then there is also a confusin with the Google-analytics-SDK for android which was also 4.    My hope by adding g4 on the end would clear up that confusion.

Comment: @DaImTo - I don't think we can do anything with the confusion here, GA is notoriously confusing in naming as you are well aware :) That said, yeah, that's a possibility. To be honest, I do not have a more elegant solution to propose here. Is there a case you can find where the 4 property was confused with Reporting API so far? If yes, then I agree with the `-ga4` prefix, if no - let's try to stick with the official mess and see how it goes. At least we will have some hard data after a while and can revisit - I took a note on keeping an eye on this

Comment: @OlegValter well i baby sit these tags so i have been doing clean up daily. It would be nice to have a consensus as to what clean up i should be doing and to limit the need for cleanup.  Do we even let the Google-analytics tag remain on questions relating to Ga4?

Comment: @DaImTo - never underestimate the ingenuity of users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-ga4+ga4. Seems like they tend to ignore the `-ga4` part. Anyways, I think we can at least all agree to synonymize [tag:ga4] -> [tag:google-analytics-ga4] to get rid of the mess partially. We can decide what to do with the naming later. I, unfortunately, do not have the score required, but can take a look what I can answer at the end of the week

Comment: @DaImTo one could argue that we can make [tag:ga4] the base tag and make a synonym of [tag:google-analytics-ga4] (decide on `-ga4` later). This way, when a user tags [tag:google-analytics], we will have a nice mapping to [tag:google-analytics] [tag:ga4]. I think it is always a good idea to keep the main tag on the question for visibility - those concerned with only a version of it, can narrow down the search

Comment: Maybe make a ga[version number] tag for each version.(ga4, ga3 ect..)

Comment: @EthanDevelops - there is a problem: there is no v3. The previous version is Universal Analytics. Now it is Google Analytics 4 property. Let's not make it harder on us by introducing confusion with Android SDK...

Comment: @Oleg Oh. I didn't realize.