# Why shouldn't we merge [google-analytics-4] into [google-analytics]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Google Analytics 4 (GA4) properties are now default in Google Analytics and are *the* replacement for Universal Analytics (UA) properties. From July 1, 2023, all standard UA properties will stop collecting data. After July 1, 2023, users will be able to access their previously processed data in their Universal Analytics property for at least six months ([source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en)).

Given standard users will be using only GA4 properties for regular measurement purposes from July 1, 2023; in my opinion, it does not make sense to have a separate [google-analytics-4] tag *any longer*. My assumption is that most Google Analytics questions from July 1, 2023 *will be* for GA4 properties. In addition, there is already a [google-analytics-api] tag for API related questions where the tag is not specific to UA or GA4 properties. Thus I suggest that we merge [google-analytics-4] into [google-analytics].

Relevant previous threads: [Google Analytics 4 tag confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402752/google-analytics-4-tag-confusion)

Comment: This sounds reasonable on the surface. This isn't like a language version upgrade, where users will still be using e.g. Python 2 long into the future; GA4 is an API/ platform, and information applicable solely to previous versions simply won't matter much anymore for most folks.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing how you see the [tag:google-analytics] and [tag:google-analytics-ga4] as being programming related?   The api tag and then tag manager are programming related.  Why do we need a web app tag on SO at all?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo: That is a valid and long standing question. But I would prefer to keep that discussion separate from the question I posted. That being said, a number of things related to [google-analytics] are not applicable to [google-analytics-api] but are programming related; for example Measurement Protocol, overlap between [gtag.js] and [google-analytics], BigQuery export, the Firebase SDK etc. I'd be happy to discuss this in further details if such a question is posted.

Comment: I disagree that gtag.js questions should be looped in under measurement protocol gtag.js may use a form of the measurement protocol. Although being that the GA4 measurement protocol is so limited I question weather or not it uses it or if it in fact uses a google only version of it.  gtag.js is not measurement protocol, it is a JavaScript SDK designed for sending hits to google analytics this is not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the issue is not as simple as you think.   While I agree the tag should just be converted into a synonym and be done with it.  There is a greater issue at hand.

There are at the time of writing this 21,009 questions tagged [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics)
These questions are a combination of the following.

- questions related to the Google analytics website for UA
- questions related to the Google analytics website for GA4
- questions related to one of several Google analytics APIs.  Gdata api (UA), Core reporting api (UA), reporting api (UA), management api (UA), measurement protocol (UA), google tag manager, real-time api (UA). As well as Data api (ga4), admin api (ga4), measurement protocol ga4.

IMO there is currently no good tag for [gtag.js](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs), which is why I have been just going with the [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tag, and IMO it's probably currently the only even remotely programming valid use for that tag.

### Web app

If we complete set aside the issue that Google analytics web application, and all web app questions should be on [webapps.stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). This is why we have a synonym on [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api) that takes everything related to Google Calendar the web app, and the same for drive.  Yet we allow the tags for [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), [gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gmail), [youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube), and [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) to accept questions related to a web application.

Since 2008 this tag has been a catch all. I have been trying to keep it clean for nearly ten years now but it is still just a collection of clutter.

### RIP UA

When UA analytics ceases to to exist. That being the date where the website stops working and we can no longer call any of the UA APIs,  a large quantity of questions will be come obsolete. They will server no purpose other then to confuse developers trying to understand now to use Google Analytics.  In a few years we will have a group of developers who have no idea there used to be something called UA analytics who will be searching for answers and run across an out of date answer and rather then getting help they will be met with nothing but frustration and confusion.

### What do we do when things become obsolete?

When systems become obsolete, the developers who create them are normally name them something unique. In the case of [google-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus), it actually became [google-people-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-people-api). This made things a little easier, although I can see there are still people tagging things [google-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-plus).

That is really not possible here.

### So what do we do?

I have no idea. The best thing IMO would be to tag all the old stuff something like [google-analytics-ua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-ua) then let all the new stuff go under [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics).  But as the tag is so cluttered currently, I think it would be hard to know if it's UA related unless you do a check for, say, everything prior to 2020 is probably UA and move all that. Then set the new tag as obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Are the platforms similar enough that most questions for Universal Analytics are also appropriate for v4?

If yes, then merging them all to use a single tag would be reasonable.

If no, then we'd want to keep them separate.  In this case the existing [google-analyics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analyics) tag should probably be renamed [google-universal-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-universal-analytics), followed by either synonymizing [google-analytics-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-4) and a new [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tag or just renaming [google-analytics-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-4) to [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics).

Comment: No GA4 and UA are completely different.   All UA questions become obsolete and useless once the system goes down.